# using JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT to display a partial -- Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.5.

I would like to know whether it is possible to render a partial via javascript/query.

If for example in my form i have a field and i would like to display the a partial only if this fields contains a value, how do i do that using javascript/jquery

Thanks for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#field').keyUp(function() { 
  if ($(this).val() == 'your required value') { 
    // load the partial through ajax
    $.get('/page.html', function(data) {
      $('#partial_container').html(data);      
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options:

1 - jquery on the field change to check for a value, if there is then send a request to the server, render the partial in the response either as html or json and update the appropriate area of the page with the response.

2 - go ahead and render the partial into a hidden div on the page when it first loads, use jquery on the field change to check for a value and if there is then un-hide the div.

Option two does not require the additional server roundtrip and due to this, barring other unspecified requirements, would likely be preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion..I prefer the first option because i would like to render the page only if data is entered in the first field..i don't want to hide an already rendered page. Er, will it be possible for me to have an example of the 1st option

Comment: @tanya @Zain beat me to it. :)